# Jenkins scripted pipeline. sh does not return stdOut if invoked script exits with non 0

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline, sh, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to get a return from 'sh' step, and it works fine for as long as the command executed by sh does not fail, if the invoked command has a non-zero exit code, sh does not return any value.

Example 1, no error

```
def myVal
myVal = sh(script: 'env && exit 0', returnStdout: true).trim()
echo "${myVal.getClass()}"
```

output:

```
class java.lang.String
```

Example 2, with error

```
def myVal
try {
    myVal = sh(script: 'env && exit 1', returnStdout: true).trim()
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    echo "${myVal.getClass()}"
}
```

output:

```
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject
```

Command that I am running sometimes fails, and I need to get the output for both successful and failed executions.
In the sh help there is this:

> Otherwise the system default shell will be run, using the -xe flags (you can specify set +e and/or set +x to disable those).

But doing this did not help:

```
myVal = sh(script: 'set +e && set +x && env && exit 1', returnStdout: true).trim()
```

same result

```
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject
```

Comment: Jenkins 2.303.3

Comment: Jenkins `sh` is idiotic.  Redirect output to a file and capture the return status then read the output from the file e.g. `sh(script: 'env > file 2>&1', returnStatus: true)` `readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/file"`.  Returning the status suppresses the exception.  See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/

Comment: This is 100% a Jenkins thing; the shell has no control over it. Writing to stderr and stdout all happens before the `exit` is run; from what you're showing us, it appears that jenkins (I almost wrote "junkins") throws away the data that was written depending on that status, even though it already has possession of it.

Comment: @Tibrogargan yeah that is exactly what I have right now, it just boggles me that It is not working as I expect it to work in this case -_-

Comment: Just confirming that the Jenkins `sh` bug is still there, 1.5 years later.